# Extract SMS messages off iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok, I've read [past posts](https://superuser.com/questions/13432/how-do-i-transfer-the-text-messages-sms-from-my-iphone-to-my-mac), and found good articles on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/#!399631/export-iphone-text-messages-to-a-spreadsheet), but I want to crowdsource my worries for a moment: Can I safely extract my SMS messages from my iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3 *without* jailbreaking *or* paying money?

I'm not scared of the SQLite db holding the info and would love to learn a bit about it in the meantime. I would likely use my MBP running 10.6 to do so, but have SUSE Linux and Win 7 systems on hand if that's easier.

Comment: If you don't want to jailbreak, a solution is to backup your iPhone in iTunes and access the backup to look for the SMS database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy SMS from Nokia phone to iPhone?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/how-to-copy-sms-from-nokia-phone-to-iphone)

Comment: The above link discusses how to get SMS without jailbreak or costs. The file is currently sitting on your computer...

Comment: Funny how both of you Loic and mankoff added a comment rather than just answering what would become the accepted answer. :P

Comment: use PhoneView to do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do a backup of your iPhone.
Backups are located here here `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`.
Find there a file called `3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28` (it might have some extension, can't remember from top of my head if it has one at all).

It is an SQLite db file so you can open in in SQLite browser of your choice then and access all your text messages.

Comment: It's important to note that this won't work if your iPhone Backups are Encrypted with an Password.

Answer (score 8):

PhoneView is awesome for the Mac, but you are on a PC. According to their FAQ:

> **Q: Is there a Windows version of PhoneView?**
>
> A: At this time, PhoneView is Mac-only. We recommend [TouchCopy](http://www.touchcopy.com/) for Windows users.

Looks like TouchCopy will do what you want.

Comment: If Phoneview is a solution, I recommend [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/).