# How do I save all MMS (with text, images & videos) from a non-jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, backup, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract SMS messages off iPhone 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11423/extract-sms-messages-off-iphone-4)

I've got a non jailbroken iPhone 3GS (iOS 4.2.1) with a lot (hundreds) of text messages and MMS. A good number of theses MMS contain photos.

Is there a way to save all this data at once on my computer (PC with Win7) without having to manually copy/paste each message content?