# SMS transfer clarification

Tags: iphone, sms

I am new to the world of iPads and iPhones, so forgive my ignorance if something sounds silly.

I am trying to find a solution for transferring my SMS messages from a Nokia backup file which only contains SMS messages (file is .nbu format) to my new iPhone 4S, and have come across a couple of answers from the user mankoff such as [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/2539)

I'm not really a programmer so I'm am a bit lost. I can find the relevant folder containg the iPhone backup, and I already know where the nokia backup is. I have a program called Notepad++, which I have used to run scripts before, but not really sure how to do this.

Is there an easier guide, or a slightly more step-by-step answer? I have two years worth of SMS and still refer to some of the messages and would hate to lose them.